# UIPageControl render quirk with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm building an iPhone application and like most I am trying to implement a UIScrollView with a UIPageControl, however I am coming across a very quirky behavior, which I assume may be a bug. Hopefully one of you has seen this before because it is driving me nuts.

Basically, the page control works fine, everything is hooked up and works normally on all accounts EXCEPT, with certain placements of the UIPageControl within the UIView, the UIPageControl will cease to render.

I'll just take screenshots of the XIB window to help illustrate... here's a placement that works perfectly fine:

http://www.jasconi.us/prob1.png

The UIPageControl is placed physically above the UIScrollView. Works great, everything is visible and working.

The next two DO NOT work:

http://www.jasconi.us/prob2.png
http://www.jasconi.us/prob3.png

The first one is simply placed below the scroll view. Doesn't render at all.

The second one is placed above the scroll view without technically being inside of it. Also doesn't render.

What the hell is up with this? I've tried using

```
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:pageControl];
```

...to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the answer to this, it's a little six degrees of Kevin Bacon.

This isn't actually a software bug, but a XIB quirk, for some reason the lower placement of the page control in combination with the default settings for autosize and anchor seem to jettison the control into outer space.

If you turn off all auto-scaling and auto-sizing and auto-anchoring and all that other crap, the controls appear exactly as you expected. The fact that it appears reliably when placed above the ScrollView is an oddity.

*shrug*.

Hope this helps future iPhone initiates.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you changed? I'm having this same problem - appears in IB, but never in the simulator. I've tried every combination of scaling, sizing, anchors that I can.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Looks like my problem was putting the control on a white background! Seems the selected dot is white, and the other dots are white with a lower alpha, so on a white background, none of them are visible!

Comment: Haha, excellent my friend. The two default auto size masks are the left and top. I turned them off and it started appearing...Good thing my app is only portrait, I feel I may have needed one or more of them if I was doing landscape.

Comment: Turning off the autosizing braces along with making the default color black worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that numberOfPages is not 0?

If you set a breakpoint can you see that pageControl is not nil?

Comment: Pages are set in code and are always greater than 0, it isn't nil because I can reference it in code just fine and manipulate values in it. I just can't *see* it.

Answer (score 0):

This will sound like a real no brainer, but I got caught out by it.

By default, `UIPageControl` expects to be on a dark background. IE: The dots are light gray, and white for the current page.

I used `UIPageControl` on it's own with no scrollview to change the time range of a graph I was rendering with `drawRect:`

Long story short, the graph background was white, so the page controller worked, I just couldn't see it. The solution was putting the graph itself in a subview, and making the parent  that contained the page control have a dark background.

Answer (score 0):

I was still encountering this exact same problem, even after trying everyone's posted answers. My issue ended up being a little more "DOH":

I was using UIPageControl at the bottom of a modal FormSheet, however, I forgot to set the size of the view as Form Sheet in the xib. This caused my page control to be off the screen and never visible.

Moral: set view size (Full, Form, Page, etc) in your xib on the base view.